# Most efficient way making an image with imagemagick

Tags: server, imagemagick, image-manipulation

Absolut beginner here.

I got the task to write a workflow to run on a server for a web-platform that uses RoR. Server is linux based.

I want to create an image. Basically, it's a background picture, already on the server, with two green squares, one in the down left and one in the right down corner. Inside the green squares is white text from two input fields on the website (left input text and right input text).

The user uploads a logo of their sports team to be resized and fitted into the upper-right corner.

I would basically do it like:

```
convert -background none -fill white -font Helvetica -pointsize 100 -size 450x -gravity center caption:“text right input“ right.png

convert -background none -fill white -font Helvetica -pointsize 100 -size 450x -gravity center caption:“text left input“ left.png

composite -gravity Center left.png base.png left_done.png

composite -gravity Center right.png base.png right_done.png

composite -gravity southeast right_done.png background.png bg_right.png

composite -gravity southwest left_done.png bg_right.png bg_left_right.png

convert Logo-upload.jpg -resize 400x230 logo_resized.png

composite -gravity NorthEast logo_resized.png bg_left_right.png done.png
```

This is step by step command line, how I would do it.

But there must be a more efficient way, isn't it?

I would love to here your comments. Just started out with very basic tasks programming very elementary things. Would love to learn more.

//Edit: The workflow may seem weird, but it was the easiest for me to get it pixel perfect on the background.png (1000x500px)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in one command line in ImageMagick, if you use parentheses processing. Here is an example using ImageMagick 6 in Unix syntax.  See https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#parenthesis

Input:

[image]

Logo:

[image]

```
convert IMG0005.jpg \
\( -size 450x -background green1 -fill white -font Helvetica -pointsize 100 -gravity center caption:"text right input" \) \
-gravity southeast -compose over -composite \
\( -size 450x -background green1 -fill white -font Helvetica -pointsize 100 -gravity center caption:"text left input" \) \
-gravity southwest -compose over -composite \
\( olympic-logo.gif -resize 400x230 \) \
-gravity northeast -compose over -composite \
IMG0005_composite.jpg
```

Result:

[image]

If on Windows, remove the back-slashes from the parentheses and change the end of line back-slash to ^.

If on ImageMagick 7, change "convert" to "magick"

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Much appreciated!